# How to Bypass Tor Browser on the NekuRay client?

Tags: tor

I want to Bypass Tor Browser on the [NekuRay](https://github.com/MatsuriDayo/nekoray) client. I tried:
[image]

But it wouldn't Bypass it.
P.S.: I don't have any idea what's CIDR (on the left section of the snapshot)

Furthermore, the process name achieved from Task Manager:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I could manage to Bypass Tor from the NekuRay client by following the proceeding configuration:
[image]